# Convert react class to react function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Hi so I have two files and i want to convert one of them into a react functional component. The first one is PuzzleGrid and it will call the function Grid.getMatrix()

```
export const PuzzleGrid = () => {
    const newMatrix = GridLib.getMatrix();
}
```

and the next is Gridlib which is a react class :

```
export class GridLib {
    static getMatrix() {
        return Array(6).fill(Array(6).fill(0));
    }
}
```

I want to be able to convert the class into a function, this is what i have, however i am getting an error. does anyone understand why?

```
export const GridLib = () => {
    GridLib.getMatrix = {
        Array(6).fill(Array(6).fill(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the results of the `getMatrix` method:

```js
export const GridLib = () => {
  return Array(6).fill(Array(6).fill(0));
}
```

However, this will cause a problem for your `PuzzleGrid` component, as it depends on `GridLib` having a `getMatrix` method.  You would have to simply have `PuzzleGrid` return a `GridLib` for it to work as such:

```js
export const PuzzleGrid = () => {
    return <GridLib />
}
```

However this pattern is a bit silly and repetetive.  I feel like there must be more going on to your question, but you may have reduced it down too much and stripped away some important details.  What is the larger context of this issue?

Comment: So I have multiple static functions in  the class `GridLib`, and `PuzzleGrid` uses these functions to compute something.

Comment: So why would you be trying to turn `GridLib` into a functional component?

Comment: This is because I no longer want to use classes.

Comment: So you'll probably want to stop relying on static methods in a `GridLib` class and use the pattern I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a function properties to declare a "static  method"

```js
export const GridLib = () => {
   return <View/> ;
}

GridLib.getMatrix = () => {
      return  Array(6).fill(Array(6).fill(0));
}
```